# Does ARM64 have intentionally undefined opcodes?

Tags: arm64, opcode

I'd like to trigger an intentional undefined opcode exception.  Does ARM64 have an instruction explicitly reserved as undefined, like x86's `ud2` and ARM32's `udf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's also called `udf`.  It appears in the ARMv8 Architecture Reference Manual on page C6-1380.  It takes an immediate operand which can be any 16-bit value and is ignored, e.g. `udf #0xdead`.

The GNU assembler added support for the `udf` mnemonic fairly recently (I believe in version 2.35, released July 2020), so if you have an older version, it may not be supported.  However, the encoding of `udf #0` is conveniently `0x00000000`, so you can just write `.inst 0` instead, or define a macro if you plan to use it a lot.

In fact, any instruction whose high 16 bits are 0 is a guaranteed `udf`, and the low 16 bits are the immediate value.  You could use different ones to mark different parts of your code, for easy spotting in a memory dump.  So you can also do `.inst 0x0000dead` if you want.

Comment: I think I see why I couldn't find it: I had the original version of the Manual. Apparently, ARM didn't reserve the UDF space until later.  (And because the first ARM64 processors don't have opcodes in this space, UDF still works on these processors.)